# Unix sort of two columns of tab-delimited file not recognizing columns as unique

Tags: sorting, unix

I am trying to sort a tab-delimited file by two columns using the following command:
`sort -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt`
but sort is combining the first and second column into one.

Here is an example of the output:

`chr11   25900447    25900461
chr11   26047696    26047711
chr1    126169385   126169400
chr11   26498396    26498411`

On line 3, this chr1 shouldn't be grouped with chr11, but sort is treating the first 1 of the second column as part of the first and sorting the rest of the number accordingly, eg:

`chr11   25900447    25900461
chr11   26047696    26047711
chr11 <-26169385    126169400
chr11   26498396    26498411`

I've tried converting to a csv, but exact same issue occurs, where it'll just ignore the , separator.

I am using sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why this issue occurs, running the command with the -V flag sorts correctly.

`sort -V -k1,1 -k2,2 file.txt`